# EF CORE Orderby query strategy for all entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I love the **Query Filers** in ef core but is there any way to have this functionality for **OrderBy**?
For example:

```
builder.Entity<Product>().HasOrderbyDescendingStrategy(p => p.Date);
```

to have the orderby clause for all queries against the database.

Comment: `HasOrderbyDescendingFilter` makes no sense because that's not a filter. Query *Filters* are for *filtering*, not *ordering*

Comment: What are you actualy asking for? you can already filter and you can Order.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto a query filer add the filter for all queries against database. If i have a date column in all entities. I want to make this orderby for those queries.

Comment: No, there's no such functionality. You'd have to hack some code on your own. You can look at this for example: https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-specifying-default-sort-order-in-ef-using-query-interceptors/

Answer (score 0):

In OnModelCreating you can specify which property will be Ordered by Annotations.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(p =>p.Date).HasColumnAnnotation(OrderConstants.OrderProperty, OrderConstants.Ascending);
```

alternatively you can write extension method for this

```
public static PrimitivePropertyConfiguration IsDefaultSort(this PrimitivePropertyConfiguration property)
{
  property.HasColumnAnnotation(OrderConstants.OrderProperty, OrderConstants.Ascending);
  return property;
}
```

and use it

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(p =>p.Date).IsDefaultSort();
```

[Reference](https://dotnetfalcon.com/stackoverflow-adventures-specifying-default-sort-order-in-ef-using-query-interceptors/)

Comment: This is an EF solution, not an EF Core solution.